# Unable to track UK Visa application

Tags: vfs-global

I am unable to track my UK Visa application which was submitted Monday 06th May 2019 and today is 22nd May 2019

I have even subscribed to SMS service yet I haven't received a single SMS till date

Further there is no benefit subscribing to VFS Worthless silver package services.

Additionally the customer care is arrogant and would have no clue why my SMS service is unavailable.

Comment: Did you try writing an email to vfs technical team in your country? You try to contact (in person) vfs office where you have applied..

Comment: Did you get to track it??